# Weird characters in json, when using get method from url

Tags: java, json

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(link, String.class);
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(response);
```

json in url:
`{"description": "Explains how to construct 45° and 90°"}`

json I'm getting:
`{"description": "Explains how to construct 45Â° and 90Â°"}`

any help to get actual json, without weird characters is apreciated.